# Avoid android camera save by default

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

i want to know if it's posible to avoid camera intent to saving the pic to the image gallery. i want to add the pic only in the internal storage, so i don't want the pic save twice on my device. Or other thing will be, delete the pic after.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056352/start-a-camera-intent-but-dont-save-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During R&D i found this ,it will defiantly solve your problem.

[Deleting a gallery image after camera intent photo taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken)